# Наследование функций C++

Tags: c++, классы, наследование

Ситуация такая. Есть класс A в котором есть функция protected virtual f. Есть класс B public наследуемый от A в котором функция f переопределена. Есть класс C public наследуемый от B и мне нужно чтобы функция f была как в A а не как в B. Наследование именно такое. Вопрос - можно ли это сделать красиво без копипаста?

Comment: Было бы неплохо в вопросе привести код, чтобы было однозначно понятно чего вы хотите. А так не совсем понятно - что значит переопределена? Переоределена - в смысле сделан override? Или переоределена с другим набором аргументов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы хотите чего-то такого?

```
struct A
{
    virtual void f() { cout << "A\n"; }
};

struct B: public A
{
    virtual void f() { cout << "B\n"; }
};

struct C: public B
{
    virtual void f() { A::f(); }
};
```